# Horizontal dynamic text scrolling with external text

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have some script that works nice if i put the text on the `Dynamic Text`, but if i load this from external `.txt` file, the text i have loaded its not inserted on the Dynamic Text.

Here is my code:

on my external txt file i use this:

```
_txt=Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
```

I use this to load the external text.

```
loadText = new LoadVars();
loadText.load("letreiro.txt");
loadText.onLoad = function() {
    _root.textoletreiro = this._txt;
    trace(_root.textoletreiro); // the Output shows the text!
    mcText._txt.text = _root.textoletreiro; // here i'm puting the text on the Dynamic Text, but is not working.
};
```

And Here my Horizontal Scrolling Code:

```
var resetPos:Number = (mcText._txt._x * -1) + 2; 
var endOfText= mcText._txt._x - (mcText._txt.textWidth + 5); 


function scroller()
{   


    mcText._txt._width = mcText._txt.textWidth;
    mcText._txt.multiline = false;
    mcText._txt.autoSize = "right";

    mcText.onEnterFrame = function() {
        mcText._txt._x -= 1;  
        if (mcText._txt._x < endOfText)
        {
            mcText._txt._x = resetPos;
            delete this["onEnterFrame"]; 
            scroller();
        }
    }
}
scroller();
```

what i'm doing wrong?

PS: Edited with the source of my `letreiro.txt`

Comment: What are you getting right now? does it not scroll at all? does it work when you use text you don't load externally?

Also,             delete this["onEnterFrame"]; 
 is a very bad idea in general... why are you deleting the onEnterFrame and resetting it over and over? it does the same thing....

Comment: What do you get if you put the following in your onLoad handler? trace("Text field: " + mcText._txt);

Comment: @net.uk.sweet if i put your tip i have this output: `Text field: _level0.instance3.mcText._txt` , but if i put this: `trace("Text field: " + mcText._txt.text);` i have the text i'm loading:
`Text field: Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.` but is not showing on the Dynamic Text Field

Comment: @net.uk.sweet something new! Now my Dynamic Text Field is showing my content. But the Scrolling is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a MovieClip on stage called mcText positioned 0,0 and inside that a TextField called _txt, then the following code scrolls your text until it hits the edge of the container then resets to 0 and scrolls again:

```
var text:String = "here is some text I would like to scroll.";
var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 32);

mcText._txt.multiline = false;
mcText._txt.wordWrap = false;
mcText._txt.autoSize = true;
mcText._txt.text = text;
mcText._txt.setTextFormat(fmt);

function scroller()
{   

    mcText.onEnterFrame = function() {
        mcText._txt._x -= 2; 

        if (Math.abs(mcText._txt._x) >= mcText._txt._width)
        {
            mcText._txt._x = 0;
            delete this["onEnterFrame"]; 
            scroller();
        }
    }
}
scroller();
```